# How to print the number of unique values in a dictionary colomn and add values in a column

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have to read a csv file named IPconnections.csv which has 147 rows like this

```
#Src IP,Dest IP, Length (Bytes)
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,58
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,471
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,54
```

and print the number of unique entries in field Dest IP or Src IP.

Basically, I want to know which IP addresses were involved in the capture file. After that, I want to know the number of bytes transferred in every pair of IP addresses.

I don't know data structures nor python. Please help.

My code:

```
import csv

f=csv.DictReader(open("IPconnections.csv",'r'))
s=set(val for dic in f for val in dic.values())
set([f])
n=0
for row in f:
    print row
    n=n+1

print "total rows are %d" %(n)
print "unique rows are %d" %len(s)
```

The `DictReader` reads it like this:

```
{
    'Dest IP': '172.16.4.240', 
    'Length (Bytes)': '60', 
    '#Src IP': '192.168.50.170'
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted this row from a print output of the above csv.DictReader. This is how it looks in notepad: #Src IP,Dest IP, Length (Bytes)
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,58
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,471
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- a `DictReader` is not really needed here (in fact, it only makes things more complicated); also, in this case the first line should probably not start with `#`
- `s` will hold not only the unique IP addresses, but also the unique number of bytes transferred
- without assigning it to some variable, `set([f])` doesn't do anything useful
- after creating `s`, the reader `f` is exhausted, so `for row in f:` does not execute at all

If you want to find the unique IP addresses and sum up the number of bytes transferred between each pair of such addresses (not entirely clear from your question and code), you could try something like this:

```
import csv, collections

with open("IPconnections.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)    # regular reader, strip spaces
    next(r)                                     # skip header row
    ips = set()                                 # holds unique IPs
    transferred = collections.defaultdict(int)  # holds sums of transf. bytes
    for src, tgt, transf in r:
        ips.add(src)                            # add to unique IPs
        ips.add(tgt)
        transferred[(src, tgt)] += int(transf)  # add to transferred
    print ips
    print transferred
```

Output:

```
set(['192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240'])
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('172.16.4.240', '192.168.50.170'): 112, 
                           ('192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240'): 591})
```

Addendum, previously in comments:

- If you want to combine bytes transferred in both directions between two IP addresses, use `transferred[frozenset([src, tgt])] += int(transf)`
- If you have problems with spaces surrounding the IP addresses despite `skipinitialspace`, add `src, tgt = src.strip(), tgt.strip()` at the top of the loop

Comment: It works like I want for the part of csv file which i shared. I ran it on my csv file which is as follows: #Src IP,Dest IP, Length (Bytes)
#Src IP,Dest IP, Length (Bytes)
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,58
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,60
192.168.50.170, 172.16.4.240,471
172.16.4.240, 192.168.50.170,54
172.16.4.240, 172.16.4.52,238
172.16.4.52, 172.16.4.240,133
172.16.4.240, 172.16.4.52,723
172.16.4.52, 172.16.4.240,89
172.16.4.240, 172.16.4.52,89
and so on. It prints repeated addresses for these.

Comment: This is my output: set(['  172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240  ', '172.16.4.52  ', '192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240 ', ' 172.16.4.240', '172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.52 ', '172.16.4.240', '   172.16.4.52', '  172.16.4.240', ' 172.16.4.52', ' 192.168.50.170'])
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {frozenset(['172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240  ']): 60, frozenset(['192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240']): 5641, frozenset(['172.16.4.52', ' 172.16.4.240']): 440, frozenset(['  172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240']): 641, frozenset(['172.16.4.52 ', ' 172.16.4.240']): 60, frozenset([' 172.16.4.240', '172.16.4.52  ']): 60,

Comment: frozenset(['172.16.4.240 ', ' 172.16.4.52']): 1514, frozenset(['172.16.4.240 ', '  172.16.4.52']): 1282, frozenset(['172.16.4.52  ', '172.16.4.240']): 641, frozenset(['172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240']): 67867, frozenset([' 172.16.4.240', '192.168.50.170']): 591, frozenset(['172.16.4.240  ', '  172.16.4.52']): 1514, frozenset([' 172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240']): 3205, frozenset(['172.16.4.52', '  172.16.4.240']): 1514, frozenset([' 192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240']): 112, frozenset(['   172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240']): 60})

Comment: I added the strip function and it worked! set(['172.16.4.52', '192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240'])
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {frozenset(['192.168.50.170', '172.16.4.240']): 6344, frozenset(['172.16.4.52', '172.16.4.240']): 78858})

Comment: Sorry that was unintentional. I have posted another question where i captured a pcap and converted to csv and want to find number of tcp connections.